# Programmatically creating a dummy certificate with private key for testing

Tags: c#, testing, certificate

I have a C# unit test project where I'd like to test some encryption extensions that I've written. I would like to use a dummy cert for testing, but I have the following restrictions:

- The build and test runs are done remotely on a machine that I do not have access to. Thus, I cannot install the certificate on the build machine.
- I cannot include secrets (such as a `.pfx` file) as part of the git repository or build, as doing so would violate security protocols. Thus, I cannot read the cert from a file included in the project.

Since I'll be doing encryption and decryption, I need to have the private key information. How can I create this cert programmatically within these restraints?

Comment: Maybe like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22237794/3245057)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a certificate for testing, convert it to a base 64 string, and then read the certificate from this string in the code. This requires four steps:

**1. Create the .cer and .pvk files**

To do this, one can use the `MakeCert.exe` tool (note that [this tool is deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa386968.aspx), and Microsoft recommends that you use the [New-SelfSignedCertificate PowerShell cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh848633). I haven't tried this, but presumably either method would work.). This is a .NET Framework tool, and is included as part of the Windows SDK. I happened to have the Windows 7 SDK installed on my machine, so for me this exe was located under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\`, but your results may vary. This tool does exactly what we want! From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(vs.80).aspx):

> **The Certificate Creation tool generates X.509 certificates for testing purposes only.** It creates a public and private key pair for digital signatures and stores it in a certificate file. This tool also associates the key pair with a specified publisher's name and creates an X.509 certificate that binds a user-specified name to the public part of the key pair.

For the sake of this example, let's call the cert `TestCert`. To create the .cer and .pvk files, run the following command:

`MakeCert.exe -sv TestCert.pvk -n "cn=Test Certificate" TestCert.cer -r`

The `-sv` flag indicates the name of the .pvk file to create, the `-n` flag is the X.500-compliant name for our certificate (it's easiest to use the *"cn=CertName"* format like above), and the `-r` flag indicates that it will be self-signed. If you want to specify the beginning and end dates for your certificate, use the `-b` and `-e` flags, and format the dates as `mm/dd/yyyy` (by default, the certificate is valid from the day of creation until 2039). If your certificate will be used for encryption and decryption (like mine), you must specify the `-sky Exchange` and `-pe` flags. You'll be prompted to create a password for the certificate during the process.

**2. Create the .pfx file**

This can be done with the [`pvk2pfx.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/pvk2pfx) tool, which should be in the same place as `MakeCert.exe`. This tool converts a .pvk and .cer file into a .pfx file. To use this tool, run the following command:

`pvk2pfx.exe -pvk TestCert.pvk -spc TestCert.cer -pfx TestCert.pfx`

The `-pvk` flag is the file name of the .pvk file to use (created in step 1), the `-spc` flag is the file name of the .cer file to use (created in step 1), and the `-pfx` flag is the name for the .pfx file that will be created. During the process, you'll be prompted to input the password you created in step 1.

**3. Get the base 64 string representation of the .pfx file**

This is pretty straightforward, and can be done with the [`Get-Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) Powershell cmdlet and the [`System.Convert.ToBase64String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string(v=vs.110).aspx) method. For this, open a Powershell window and run the following:

```
$content = Get-Content TestCert.pfx -Encoding Byte
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($content) | Out-File "TestCert.txt"
```

Now we have the base 64 string for our .pfx file in TestCert.txt.

**4. Create the certificate programmatically**

Now we can create the certificate in the code like so:

```
namespace MyTests
{
    using System;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

    public class MyTests
    {
        // Copy and paste the string from TestCert.txt here.
        private const string CertText = "<text>";

        // Use the password you created in steps 1 and 2 here.
        private const string Password = "p4ssw0rd";

        // Create the certificate object.
        private readonly X509Certificate2 TestCert = new X509Certificate2(
            Convert.FromBase64String(MyTests.CertText),
            MyTests.Password);
    }
}
```