# .Net core web api not support with the HTTPS

Tags: .net-core, https, service-worker

I have created web api using .NetCore. After that I have change it to Windows background Service. Now my api is working as a background service.But its only listen to the HTTP request. When I used HTTPS its not listen to the request.

Currently its support only this url `http://localhost:8080/Customer`. But I need to use it like this `https://localhost:8080/Customer`.

Someone can please tell me how we can start new service listen to the https request. When I tried to use HTTPS I got this error message.

```
 Application: MHScaleInboundWebAPI.exe
CoreCLR Version: 5.0.1021.41214
.NET Version: 5.0.10
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Reload()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at MHScaleInboundWebAPI.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\IRM\mhscaleinboundwebapi\Program.cs:line 10
```

Comment: REST API is by default HTTP. You need an SSL for HTTPS requests.

Comment: Yes I need to use HTTPS listener. So how can I do it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api

Comment: I am not using IIS for this. I am using Kestrel server.

Comment: have you tried running the commands in the error message?

Comment: Yes I have used few commands. but still I am getting this error message

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate Trusted Self-Signed Certificate in .NetCore Console Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53258151/generate-trusted-self-signed-certificate-in-netcore-console-application)