# How to create ISignatureFactory for creating a self-signed certificate

Tags: c#, x509certificate, x509, x509certificate2, self-signed-certificate

I am trying to use c# to generate a `X509Certificate2`.

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22237794/14357365) which is what I am looking for. But, that code is using absolute methods.

The method `SetSignatureAlgorithm` has the following warning

> Not needed if Generate used with an ISignatureFactory

Also, the code `certificateGenerator.Generate(issuerPrivateKey, random)` has the following message

> Use Generate with an ISignatureFactory

How can I create a `ISignatureFactory` to fix these two warnings?

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?  This method generates a private key on the fly, signs it with a self-signed certificate and returns the cert and key as a PKCS#12 bundle (can be saved in a .pfx file if need be).

```cs
public static X509Certificate2 CreateX509CryptCertificate(string name, int keyLength = 2048, int yearsValid = 3) {
    X509KeyStorageFlags storageFlags = X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | 
                                       X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable;
    using var rsa = RSA.Create(keyLength);
    var request = new CertificateRequest($"CN={name}", rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    using X509Certificate2 ephemeral = request.CreateSelfSigned(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddYears(yearsValid));
    return new X509Certificate2(ephemeral.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12), string.Empty, storageFlags);
}
```

Comment: This method does not have a password.

Comment: @Jay What format do you need the private key in?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way

```cs
var randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
var random = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);
var subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory(PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Sha256WithRsaEncryption.ToString(), subjectKeyPair.Private, random);
```